# Xcode 7 error message "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted" when app runs on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am using Xcode 7.2. When I run my app on simulator iOS 9.2, there is no error message. However, when I run my app on iPad iOS 9.2, there is error message

> error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted

What does the error message means? How do I get rid of the error message when running on iPad?